# mpi_gather of two variables

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am new to MPI programming with Fortran. I want to plot a 2D graph. I am trying to let each processor calculate one point of graph and send it to root to write it on file. Can somebody tell me how to send two variables viz: `x` and `f(x)` with `mpi_gather`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `MPI_Gather` works with arrays. Simply put both values in one array with 2 elements. The more elegant way would be to define a Fortran type to hold both values and then create a structured MPI type with `MPI_Type_create_struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example of both what Hristo said and " [Is there anything wrong with passing an unallocated array to a routine without an explicit interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496510/is-there-anything-wrong-with-passing-an-unallocated-array-to-a-routine-without-a/13496808#13496808) " here's how you might do it

```
Program gather

  Use mpi

  Implicit None

  Integer, Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: result

  Integer, Dimension( 1:2 ) :: buffer

  Integer :: me, nprocs, error
  Integer :: x, fx

  Call mpi_init( error )

  Call mpi_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, me    , error )
  Call mpi_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, nprocs, error )

  If( me == 0 ) Then
     Allocate( result( 1:2, 1:nprocs ) ) !Naughty - should check stat
  Else
     Allocate( result( 1:0, 1:0 ) )      !Naughty - should check stat
  End If

  x  = me
  fx = x * x

  buffer( 1 ) = x
  buffer( 2 ) = fx

  Call mpi_gather( buffer, 2, mpi_integer, &
                   result, 2, mpi_integer, &
                   0, mpi_comm_world, error )

  If( me == 0 ) Then
     Write( *, '( 99999( i3, 1x ) )' ) result( 1, : ) 
     Write( *, '( 99999( i3, 1x ) )' ) result( 2, : ) 
  End If

  Call mpi_finalize( error )

End Program gather
Wot now? mpif90 gather.f90
Wot now? mpirun -np 7 ./a.out
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
  0   1   4   9  16  25  36
```