# MPI_Scatterv in Fortran crashes with Abort trap signal

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have write a master-slave IO function with Fortran. First, I read the file with 0 process, put the data in the array `read_buffer`, and then I call subroutine"scatter_data".
I have created some communicators to scatter data from process 0 to process 0-8.
These communicators are like this:

```
2,  5,  8  :sub_io_communicator (In this sub_io_communicator , sub_iorank is /0, 1, 2/ )
1,  4,  7  :sub_io_communicator (In this sub_io_communicator , sub_iorank is /0, 1, 2/ )
0,  3,  6  :sub_io_communicator (In this sub_io_communicator , sub_iorank is /0, 1, 2/ )
2,  1,  0  :master_communicator

                      DATA
                       ||
                 0 process read
                       ||
                        0           call MPI_scatterv in communicator "master_communicator"    
                /       |      \    
               0        1        2  call MPI_scatterv in communicator "sub_io_communicator" 
             / | \    / | \    / | \
            0  3  6  1  4  7  2  5  8
```

but when I call MPI_Scatterv, it crashes. I use "print" to debug it , and find the bug is in "call MPI_Scatterv". SO, I write a very simple MPI_Scatterv in this subroutine to see whether it will work, but it does not.

My code is like this :

```
SUBROUTINE scatter_data(read_buffer,ne_in)

use naqpms_nest, only : nest, nxlo, nylo, ratio, nx, ny
implicit none
include 'mpif.h'

integer, INTENT(IN) :: ne_in
integer :: ierr
integer :: location
integer :: ii, jj, kk, zz, dd, send_size,receive_size
real, INTENT(IN), dimension(nx(ne_in)*ny(ne_in)) :: read_buffer
integer, dimension(nx(ne_in)*ny(ne_in)) :: read_buffer_int
real,     allocatable  :: rerange_buffer(:)   
integer,     allocatable  :: receive_buffer_int(:)   
integer , allocatable  :: counts_recv(:),displacements(:)
integer                :: distance,left_bdy,left_bdy2,rigth_bdy,rigth_bdy2
integer :: tmp1(3), tmp2(3)

IF( sub_iorank.EQ.0 ) THEN
    if(allocated(counts_recv))deallocate(counts_recv)
    if(allocated(displacements))deallocate(displacements)
    if(allocated(receive_buffer))deallocate(receive_buffer)
    if(allocated(rerange_buffer))deallocate(rerange_buffer)

    IF( master_iorank.EQ.0) THEN
        allocate(counts_recv(dims(2,ne_in)))
        allocate(displacements(dims(2,ne_in)))
    ENDIF

    print*,"location",my_rank,nx(ne_in), ey(ne_in), sy(ne_in)

    receive_size = nx(ne_in) * (ey(ne_in)-sy(ne_in)+1)
    allocate(receive_buffer(receive_size))
    allocate(receive_buffer_int(receive_size))
    allocate(rerange_buffer(receive_size))

    CALL MPI_Gather(receive_size, 1, MPI_INTEGER, counts_recv, 1, MPI_INTEGER,&
                     0, master_communicator ,ierr )


    tmp1(1:3)= (/1,1,1/)
    tmp2(1:3)= (/0,1,2/)
    IF(my_rank==0)print*,"counts_recv",counts_recv        
    CALL mpi_scatterv (counts_recv, tmp1, tmp2, MPI_INT,&                       ! this is just for test
                       receive_size, 1, mpi_int, 0, master_communicator, ierr )
    print*,my_rank,receive_size

    IF(my_rank.EQ.0) THEN
        displacements(1)=0
        do ii=2, dims(2,ne_in)
            displacements(ii) = displacements(ii-1) + counts_recv(ii-1)
        enddo
    ENDIF
    IF(my_rank==0)print*,displacements,counts_recv
    CALL mpi_scatterv (read_buffer, counts_recv, displacements, mpi_real,&
                       receive_buffer, receive_size, mpi_real, 0, master_communicator, ierr )

    IF(my_rank==0)print*,"mpi_scatterv one ok",my_rank
ENDIF!sub_iorank =0



IF(sub_iorank .EQ. 0) THEN
    if(allocated(counts_recv))deallocate(counts_recv)
    if(allocated(displacements))deallocate(displacements)
    allocate(counts_recv(dims(1,ne_in)))
    allocate(displacements(dims(1,ne_in)))
ENDIF

receive_size =(ex(ne_in)-sx(ne_in)+1)*(ey(ne_in)-sy(ne_in)+1)
CALL MPI_Gather(receive_size, 1, MPI_INTEGER, counts_recv, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, sub_io_communicator ,ierr )

IF(sub_iorank .EQ. 0) THEN
    displacements(1)=0                
    do ii=2,dims(1,ne_in)                 
        displacements(ii) = displacements(ii-1) + counts_recv(ii-1)
    enddo
ENDIF

IF(sub_iorank .EQ. 0) THEN
    DO dd = 1, dims(1,ne_in)
        DO jj = 1, bdy_gather(4,dd,ne_in)-bdy_gather(3,dd,ne_in)+1
            distance = bdy_gather(2,dd,ne_in)-bdy_gather(1,dd,ne_in)+1
            left_bdy = (jj-1)*nx(ne_in) + bdy_gather(1,dd,ne_in)
            rigth_bdy = (jj-1)*nx(ne_in) + bdy_gather(2,dd,ne_in)
            left_bdy2 = displacements(dd) + (jj-1)*distance + 1  
            rigth_bdy2 = displacements(dd) + (jj-1)*distance + distance
            rerange_buffer( left_bdy2 : rigth_bdy2) = receive_buffer(left_bdy : rigth_bdy )

        ENDDO
    ENDDO
ENDIF

if(allocated(receive_buffer))deallocate(receive_buffer)
allocate(receive_buffer(receive_size))
IF(sub_iorank .EQ. 0) print*, my_rank, counts_recv, displacements
 CALL mpi_scatterv( rerange_buffer, counts_recv, displacements, mpi_real,&
                     receive_buffer, receive_size, mpi_real, 0, sub_io_communicator,ierr)
IF(sub_iorank .EQ. 0) print*,"mpi_scatterv ok"

END SUBROUTINE scatter_data
```

I run this code : mpirun -np 9 ./gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx0307.exe

then, the error in the log file is like this :

```
 location           0          88          26           1
 location           1          88          52          27
 location           2          88          77          53
 counts_recv        2288        2288        2200
           1        2288
           2        2200
*** Error in forrtl: error (76): Abort trap signal
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  00000000007A5F3A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.17.s  00002BA00DADA5D0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002BA00E01F207  gsignal               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002BA00E0208F8  abort                 Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002BA00E061D27  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002BA00E06A489  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libmpi.so.12.0     00002BA00CAC2AED  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libmpi.so.12.0     00002BA00CAC4A54  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libmpi.so.12       00002BA00CAC3188  MPI_Scatterv          Unknown  Unknown
libmpifort.so.12.  00002BA00D445A7A  mpi_scatterv          Unknown  Unknown
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  0000000000475EA4  naqpms_parallel_m        1269  naqpms_parallel.f90
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  00000000005953BF  rd_met_pyramid_           151  rd_met_pyramid.f90
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  0000000000617709  read_data_                 61  naqpms_readdata.f90
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  0000000000647BA4  naqpms_calc_mp_ca         141  naqpms_calc.f90
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  000000000065A835  MAIN__                     86  main.f90
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  000000000040B45E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002BA00E00B3D5  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
gnaqpms.v1.6.0_jx  000000000040B369  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Comment: please trim and port a [mcve]

Comment: On first glance 1) You pass an unallocated allocatable array to a routine which doesn't have an allocatable dummy argument - this is not valid fortran, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496510/is-there-anything-wrong-with-passing-an-unallocated-array-to-a-routine-without-a    2) MPI_INT is *not* part of the MPI Fortran binding, use MPI_INTEGER   3) Do **not** include the mpi header file, this shouldn't have been done in decades - use the mpi module, it will help you catch many more errors (possibly including 1). But without a minimal example it is difficult to say more

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I will port a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It seems that the unallocated array may indeed be the issue. However, please do not use "it cannot work" or "it does not work". Instead, tell what happens. Tell "It crashed with this error message" or "My results are wrong and look like this". See [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your remind .  I will post a minimal reproducible example with more messages.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @IanBush You mean: "use the mpif08 module". That one does fairly good error checking because of strict type matching. The `mpif.h` and `use mpi` will be deprecated soon.

Comment: Please do not use the term "m-s" anymore. All technical writing guidelines of the past number of years advise against this. You can use "master-worker" or even "manager-worker".

Comment: @VictorEijkhout No, I mean `use mpi`. I would prefer `use mpi_f08` but the former is a big step up from the include file, and does at least have a chance of catching such an issue, depending upon the quality of implementation. `Use mpi_f08` would be better, but requires changing existing code - which may be an issue here, I don't know.