# Fortran Derived Type cannot Access Other Parameters

Tags: fortran

I have defined the following *derived type* in Fortran:

```
type :: derived_type
    logical :: is_allocated = .false.
    integer :: n_layer = 0
    integer :: type = 0
    real, allocatable :: radius(:)
end type derived_type
```

I then define a variable with this *derived type* in a subroutine:

```
type(derived_type), intent(inout) :: sphere(15)
```

However, when I try to call `sphere(1)%type`, such as through `print`, later in the subroutine, I receive a segmentation fault error instead of the expected `0`. I have tried renaming `type` to some other name because I was thinking that `type` might be a *reserved name*, but it still returns a segmentation fault. Weirdly enough, `sphere(1)%is_allocated` is defined and it returns `.false.`. I tried moving the `integer :: type = 0` at the top of the list and it returns the correct value, but calling the other parameters return a segmentation fault.

I am not an expert in Fortran and I don't know what could be the problem here? I am using gfortran 9.4.0 in compiling the script.

The code itself is part of a bigger script and the error log seems to point to a part similar to what I mentioned.

**Update**

Here is a minimal reproducible example.

*shape_type.mod*

```
module shape_type
    type :: shape_params
        logical :: is_allocated = .false.
        integer :: type = 0
        real(8), allocatable :: perimeter(:)
    end type shape_params
end module shape_type
```

*shape_list.mod*

```
module shape_list
    use shape_type, only: shape_params

    type :: shape_list_params
        logical :: is_allocated = .false.
        type(shape_params), allocatable :: geometry(:)
    end type shape_list_params
end module shape_list
```

*test_subroutine.f90*

```
subroutine test_subroutine(geometry)
    use shape_type, only: shape_params

    implicit none

    type(shape_params), intent(inout) :: geometry(15)

    print *, geometry(1)%is_allocated
    print *, geometry(1)%type
end subroutine test_subroutine
```

*main_program.f90*

```
program main_program
    use shape_list, only: shape_list_params

    implicit none

    type(shape_list_params), save, dimension(1) :: form

    call test_subroutine(form(1)%geometry)
end program
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It outputs a tidy "0" for me. Show a small but complete, compileable program with your error. Are you sure that the dimension in your subroutine matches the dimension in the calling routine?

Comment: Please check the documentation on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The segfault might be caused by a totally different part of your program. For example show where you call `allocate()` for `derived_type%radius`.

Comment: You definitely have to show more code, otherwise we can only try guessing

Comment: Where do you allocate `form(1)%geometry` to have (at least) 15 elements before passing it to `test_subroutine`

Comment: `form(1)%geometry` is not allocated when you pass it to `test_subroutine()`

Comment: Wouldn't `form(1)%geometry` be allocated upon defining it in the `main_program`, although `geometry` will have a dynamic size? The problem I am having is `geometry(1)%is_allocated` is defined, but `geometry(1)%type` is not. The reverse happens when I interchange them in `shape_type.mod`.

Comment: @magus_e No, `form(1)%geometry` will not be allocated. It is allocatable, and you haven't allocated it, end of story. What size do you expect it to be? I suspect this is effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496510/is-there-anything-wrong-with-passing-an-unallocated-array-to-a-routine-without-a/13496808#13496808 .

Comment: Note also real( 8 ) is not portable, might not be supported by your compiler and might not do what you expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: I understand where your misunderstanding is: you think that by declaring `geometry(15)` in `test_subroutine()`, it will allocate geometry with a size of 15. But it doesn't work like this: `geometry` is a dummy argument, and `geometry(15)` assumes that the actual argument (which is `form(1)%geometry`) has been previously allocated with a size of 15, which is not the case.

Comment: There's also the point that there is no interface in scope when calling  test_subroutine from main and shape params is not a sequence derived type - I forget the actual rules here, save the basic practical one which catches all these: Stick all subprograms in a module to make sure you have an interface in scope when called.

Comment: @IanBush I think that in such a case it's OK as soon as the type is defined within a module. But yes, putting everything in a module is recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I was able to get pass through this particular problem (and with a new problem now) in the script. Unfortunately, the bigger script, which this script is part of, is not mine and it's support has ended. The modules are separated since this is how they appear in the bigger script.

Comment: Off-topic detail: with compiled langages we don't talks about "scripts", but about "source codes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate all variables which have the `allocatable` attribute explicitly. This will not be done by the Fortran compiler automatically, you have to care for it yourself: [Allocatable Arrays](https://fortran-lang.org/en/learn/best_practices/allocatable_arrays/).

Your program works after allocating the variable with `allocate()` like this:

```
program main_program
    use shape_list, only: shape_list_params

    implicit none

    type(shape_list_params), save, dimension(1) :: form

    allocate(form(1)%geometry(15))  ! allocation added
    call test_subroutine(form(1)%geometry)
end program
```

Some comments:

- Your program has a second occurence of `allocatable` for which you need to care: `real(8), allocatable :: perimeter(:)`. You either need to allocate this also, or since it is only a single value, you could remove the attribute.
- You do not need to track allocation yourself with `is_allocated`. Better use Fortran's intrinsic [allocated](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ALLOCATED.html).
- The `save` attribute in your main program will not have any effect. It is useful only in subroutines and functions to keep the values of variables until the next call.
- Your minimal reproducible example has two wrong file extensions: *shape_type.mod* and *shape_list.mod*. All files must have the `.f90` extension. But that is most probably only a copy and paste error.

Comment: Note that the `allocate()` statement is not the only way to allocate an object. Allocating on assignement is also possible.

Comment: Good point, I extended my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to list all the ways an allocatable variable may become allocated, then it's still not complete.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I removed the misleading sentence for now. Do you have a reference for all the ways?

Comment: There's the `move_alloc()` intrinsic routine

Comment: You can probably do something horrendous with the extended C interop as well

Comment: Thank you for these! I am now able to get pass the errors (and working with a new error now). Unfortunately, the bigger script, which this is part of, is not mine, and its support has ended. The `save` and `is_allocated` are there since they appear in the bigger script and I included them here thinking that it might relevant.

Comment: You're welcome!