# Processing a shared array by a passed index in a subroutine in a parallel loop

Tags: fortran, openmp

In a parallel loop, I process a shared array using a subroutine to which I pass the array and the current private-do index as parameters, but the program crashes with an array out-of-bounds error. How to correctly call a subroutine to process a shared array and pass the parallel loop index to it?

Code in the main.F:

```fortran
      PROGRAM TESTER
         USE OMP_LIB
         USE PRINTER
       
         INTEGER, PARAMETER:: N = 5
                  
         REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE, SAVE :: ARG_1, ARG_2
         REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: RES
          
C=======================================================================
C$OMP THREADPRIVATE(ARG_1, ARG_2)
C=======================================================================         

         ALLOCATE(RES(N))
         PRINT *,'MAIN: "RES" IS ALLOCATED = ', 
     >      ALLOCATED(RES)

C$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(I) SHARED(RES) NUM_THREADS(2)  

         ALLOCATE(ARG_1(N))
         PRINT *,'MAIN: "ARG_1" IS ALLOCATED = ', 
     >      ALLOCATED(ARG_1)
         
         ALLOCATE(ARG_2(N))
         PRINT *,'MAIN: "ARG_2" IS ALLOCATED = ', 
     >      ALLOCATED(ARG_2)

C Step 1:Initialize working arrays:        
         CALL WORK1(ARG_1,N, ARG_2,N) 
         CALL WORK2(ARG_1,N, ARG_2,N)
        
C Step 2: Print working arrays: 
         CALL PRINT_ARR(ARG_1,N)
         CALL PRINT_ARR(ARG_2,N)

         PRINT *,'===================================='
         
C Step 3: Parallel Loop:
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP DO 
         DO I=1,N
            CALL WORK3(RES,I,ARG_1(I),ARG_2(I))
         ENDDO
C$OMP END DO
         CALL PRINT_ARR(RES,N)
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP END PARALLEL
         DEALLOCATE(ARG_1,ARG_2)
         DEALLOCATE(RES)
    
      END PROGRAM TESTER
```

Code of work.F file:

```fortran
      SUBROUTINE WORK1(ARG_ARR_1,DIM_1,ARG_ARR_2,DIM_2)
         INTEGER DIM_1, DIM_2,I,J
         REAL*4 ARG_ARR_2(DIM_2)
         REAL*4 ARG_ARR_1(DIM_1)
         REAL*4 ARG1, ARG2
         REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: ARG_ARR_3
         
         SAVE
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP THREADPRIVATE (I)         
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
         DO I=1,DIM_1
            ARG_ARR_1(I)= 1.0
         ENDDO
         RETURN
      ENTRY WORK2 (ARG_ARR_1,DIM_1,ARG_ARR_2,DIM_2)  
         DO I=1,DIM_2
            ARG_ARR_2(I)= 2.0
         ENDDO
         RETURN
      ENTRY WORK3 (ARG_ARR_3,J,ARG1,ARG2)
         ARG_ARR_3(J)= ARG1+ARG2
         RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE WORK1
```

And module.f code:

```fortran
      MODULE PRINTER
     
         CONTAINS 

            SUBROUTINE PRINT_ARR(ARR_VAR,SIZE)
               REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: ARR_VAR
               INTEGER SIZE
               INTEGER,SAVE:: J
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP THREADPRIVATE(J)               
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
               DO J=1,SIZE
                  PRINT *,'ARR_VAR(',J,')=',ARR_VAR(J)
               ENDDO    
               FLUSH(6)            
            END SUBROUTINE PRINT_ARR

      END MODULE PRINTER
```

My compile and run commands:

```
gfortran -fopenmp -O0 -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -c module1.f work.F main.F
gfortran -fopenmp *.o -o a.x
./a.x
```

My output:

```
 MAIN: "RES" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 MAIN: "ARG_1" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 MAIN: "ARG_2" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   2.00000000    
 ====================================
 MAIN: "ARG_1" IS ALLOCATED =  T

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
 MAIN: "ARG_2" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   2.00000000    
 ====================================
At line 21 of file work.F
Fortran runtime error: Index '4' of dimension 1 of array 'arg_arr_3' above upper bound of 2

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f1e90ed3ad0 in ???
#1  0x7f1e90ed2c35 in ???
#2  0x7f1e90c8051f in ???
    at ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
#3  0x55d38d47e43d in master.0.work1
    at .../work.F:21
#4  0x55d38d47e04f in work3_
    at .../work.F:20
#5  0x55d38d47dae6 in MAIN__._omp_fn.0
    at .../main.F:44
#6  0x7f1e90e7aa15 in ???
#7  0x55d38d47d45b in tester
    at .../main.F:18
#8  0x55d38d47d58d in main
    at .../main.F:2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I use gfortran: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

Comment: 1) I don't know why you need the `SAVE` statement in `WORK1()`, but saved variables do not work well with multithreading. And without `SAVE` you don't need to declare `I` as `THREADPRIVATE`; 2) have you put the `WORK1()` routine in a module? You can't define an allocatable dummy argument if the routine is not called with an explicit interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! All this code is a toy model of big legacy code that I am modernizing and using this model to plan future changes. 1) I had to describe ```I``` as private, because practice shows that in called procedures everything that indexes arrays must be marked threadprivate to avoid an runtime error "loop index has been changed". 2) I didn't know that a dummy argument can be allocatable only in a module, thanks. But the whole point of the question is that I don’t know how to pass RES array to WORK3 subroutine. No, the ```WORK1```  subroutine is not in the module.

Comment: Do yourself a big favour and get rid of the alternate `Entry` points before you even think about allocatables, let alone parallelism. Even if it is defined by the standard (I suspect so but hope not) the mix of archaic and early modern features could well lead to compiler bug hell.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496510/is-there-anything-wrong-with-passing-an-unallocated-array-to-a-routine-without-a/13496808#13496808 for more details on passing allocatables

Comment: *"practice shows that in called procedures everything that indexes arrays must be marked threadprivate to avoid an runtime error "loop index has been changed"*: that's just wrong, and the problem comes the `SAVE` statement. If no `SAVE`, no need of `THREADPRIVATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answer and comments, @PierU and @IanBush ! I apologize for the long response!
I would like to supplement my words regarding keywords `threadprivate` and `save`:

- the code I'm working with has ~70k lines in about 100+ files, which contain subroutines with hundreds or thousands of lines, and almost all of these subroutines have a standing alone `SAVE` statement, without a list of variables and acting for all locals variables in scope. In my example here I simulate this environment and for critical variables such as loop counters/array iterators I am forced to use `threadprivate` statement.
- However, you are absolutely right that this construction (`SAVE` + `THREADPRIVATE` variables lists) should be used as rarely as possible. In my target code, these subroutines are called inside a large OpenMP loop and mark explicitly some their local variables as `private` is impossible.
- Everything that has been said also applies to using `entry`: it is part of legacy environment and I would like to place all code in modules and avoid a lot of problems, but now I don’t have the time for that.

As a result, I was able to make my own solution, which I present below. The point is in the correct description of shared variables: array Y must be *shared* (as a module variable).

main.F:

```fortran
      PROGRAM TESTER
         USE OMP_LIB
         USE PRINTER
                  
         REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE, SAVE :: ARG_1, ARG_2
         REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: RES
          
C=======================================================================
C$OMP THREADPRIVATE(ARG_1, ARG_2)
C=======================================================================         

         ALLOCATE(RES(N))
         ALLOCATE(Y(N))
         PRINT *,'MAIN: "RES" IS ALLOCATED = ', 
     >      ALLOCATED(RES)
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(I) SHARED(Y) NUM_THREADS(2)  
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
         ALLOCATE(ARG_1(N))
         PRINT *,'MAIN: "ARG_1" IS ALLOCATED = ', 
     >      ALLOCATED(ARG_1)
         
         ALLOCATE(ARG_2(N))
         PRINT *,'MAIN: "ARG_2" IS ALLOCATED = ', 
     >      ALLOCATED(ARG_2)

C Initialize working arrays:        
         CALL WORK1(ARG_1,N, ARG_2,N) 
         CALL WORK2(ARG_1,N, ARG_2,N)
        
C Step 1: Print working arrays: 
         CALL PRINT_ARR(ARG_1,N)
         CALL PRINT_ARR(ARG_2,N)

         PRINT *,'===================================='
         FLUSH(6)

C Step 2: Parallel Loop:
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP DO 
         DO I=1,N
c            RES(I)=ARG_1(I) + ARG_2(I)
            CALL WORK3(I,ARG_1(I),ARG_2(I))
         ENDDO
C$OMP END DO
         CALL PRINT_ARR(Y,N)
         DEALLOCATE(ARG_1,ARG_2)
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP END PARALLEL
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
         
         DEALLOCATE(RES)
    
      END PROGRAM TESTER
```

work.F:

```fortran
      SUBROUTINE WORK1(ARG1_W1,DIM_1,ARG2_W2,DIM_2)
         USE PRINTER
c------ Input arguments: -----------------------------------------------         

         INTEGER DIM_1, DIM_2, J
         REAL*4 ARG2_W2(DIM_2)
         REAL*4 ARG1_W1(DIM_1)
c dummy arguments for WORK3:         
         REAL*4 ARG1_W3, ARG2_W3
c------ Locals: -------------------------------------------------------- 
        
         INTEGER I
         SAVE I
c------ OpenMP spells: -------------------------------------------------         
c$OMP THREADPRIVATE (I)         
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
         DO I=1,DIM_1
            ARG1_W1(I) = 1.0
         ENDDO
         RETURN
      ENTRY WORK2 (ARG1_W1,DIM_1,ARG2_W2,DIM_2)  
         DO I=1,DIM_2
            ARG2_W2(I) = 2.0
         ENDDO
         RETURN
      ENTRY WORK3 (J,ARG1_W3,ARG2_W3)

         Y(J)= ARG1_W3 + ARG2_W3
         RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE WORK1
```

module1.f:

```fortran
      MODULE PRINTER
         INTEGER, PARAMETER:: N = 5
c NB: array Y is shared!
         REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE::Y
         
         CONTAINS 

            SUBROUTINE PRINT_ARR(ARR_VAR,SIZE)
               REAL*4,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: ARR_VAR
               INTEGER SIZE
               INTEGER,SAVE:: J
c------ OpenMP spells: -------------------------------------------------               
c$OMP THREADPRIVATE(J)       
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------        
               DO J=1,SIZE
                  PRINT *,'ARR_VAR(',J,')=',ARR_VAR(J)
               ENDDO    
               FLUSH(6)            
            END SUBROUTINE PRINT_ARR

      END MODULE PRINTER
```

My compilation and run commands:

```
sudo rm -R -f {*.o,*.x,*.mod}
gfortran -fopenmp -O0 -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -c module1.f work.F main.F
gfortran -fopenmp *.o -o a.x
./a.x
```

My output (there may be some disorder in the output due to multiple threads):

```
 MAIN: "RES" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 MAIN: "ARG_1" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 MAIN: "ARG_2" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   2.00000000    
 ====================================
 MAIN: "ARG_1" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 MAIN: "ARG_2" IS ALLOCATED =  T
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   1.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   2.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   2.00000000    
 ====================================
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           1 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           2 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           3 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           4 )=   3.00000000    
 ARR_VAR(           5 )=   3.00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't bring the full solution here, but it's difficult to elaborate in comments.

- First, you have to get rid of the `SAVE` statement in the `WORK1()`, which is a potential killer for multithreading.
- Then, threadprivatising `I` is no longer needed.
- You don't need the allocate attribute on the `ARG_ARR_3` argument (and it won't work anyway, unless you put the routine in a module):

```
      SUBROUTINE WORK1(ARG_ARR_1,DIM_1,ARG_ARR_2,DIM_2)
         INTEGER DIM_1, DIM_2,I,J
         REAL*4 ARG_ARR_2(DIM_2)
         REAL*4 ARG_ARR_1(DIM_1)
         REAL*4 ARG1, ARG2
         REAL*4 ARG_ARR_3(*)

         DO I=1,DIM_1
            ARG_ARR_1(I)= 1.0
         ENDDO
         RETURN
      ENTRY WORK2 (ARG_ARR_1,DIM_1,ARG_ARR_2,DIM_2)  
         DO I=1,DIM_2
            ARG_ARR_2(I)= 2.0
         ENDDO
         RETURN
      ENTRY WORK3 (ARG_ARR_3,J,ARG1,ARG2)
         ARG_ARR_3(J)= ARG1+ARG2
         RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE WORK1
```

Also, in your main program the `THREADPRIVATE(ARG_1, ARG_2)` is overkill: `threadprivate` aims at getting persistent private variables between parallel region. I can't see the need here. Keep things simple and declare instead:

```
C$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(I,ARG_1,ARG_2) SHARED(RES) NUM_THREADS(2)
```

Last, `DEALLOCATE(ARG_1,ARG_2)` should be placed before the end of the parallel region.

Try with that... But this is definitely a poor design (`ENTRY` is a resurgence from the past, as well as the fixed-form source).

Comment: Thanks for the note about ```deallocate``` before parallel region.